# Creating posts with php-script + csv

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields, import, csv

I'm trying to create posts with a Script + CSV. Each row schould create a post, while each column should fill the title/ACF-Fields.

```
$csv_file_path = '/test.csv';

function create_wp_cpt_from_csv() {
    global $csv_file_path;
    if (($handle = fopen($csv_file_path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            $post = array(
                'post_title' => $data[0],
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'sorten'
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
            update_field('acf_1', $data[1], $post_id);
            update_field('acf_2', $data[2], $post_id);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

add_action('init', 'create_link_to_import_csv');

function create_link_to_import_csv() {
    add_menu_page( 'Import CSV', 'Import CSV', 'manage_options', 'import_csv', 'import_csv_function');
}

function import_csv_function(){
    create_wp_cpt_from_csv();
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I implemented this code in my functions.php. CSV is in the same directory as the functions.php.

Unfortunately, whenever i run the script via clicking on the "Import CSV" in the admin-backend, it just opens the following link, but it doesn't create posts:

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=import_csv

Theme: Impreza

Are certain permissions missing here? Can this work at all via the functions.php? Have i built in a general error in the function?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I notice you're calling `wp_insert_post` but you're assuming it succeeded and not checking for failure/errors. I also see that you've muddled up CPT's and posts, and was expecting to see calls to `register_post_type` when I read the title of your question. Try to be specific and accurate with the terminology you used, you're trying to create posts, not CPT's. Also is there code missing? You mentioned clicking a button but there are no buttons in your questions code, and if I read it right the import happens immediatley and there is no output on the page. Use the edit link to update your Q

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your answer. I edited my Q.

Comment: `$post_id` could be a `WP_Error` object, not a post ID, you should use `if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {` to check this and print the error message out. You should also print out a message saying the post was succesful, your page doesn't have to be a blank screen, and you shouldn't have to then go to the posts page to discover if it worked or not, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/#comment-1973